# Inserting data from one table to another table almost working

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database, the first table called **users** and it contains:
id, firstname, lastname, email, password, hash, active.

The second table called **listing** and it contains:
user_id, user_email, listing_id, listing_title, list_description, listing _country, listing_city, listing_image.

I want to make sure that when a user is logged in to the website and creates a new listing, the listing will be recognized by id and email.

So basically i want to take the information from id and email that is on the **users** table and to insert it to the user_id and user_email columns on the **listing** table.

And i did it, sort of.

The problem is that if i'm logged in to the website and create a listing, the database shows the wrong user_id and user_email on the **listing** table.
So for example:

if i'm logged in as john@johndoe.com with the user id of 1 and i will create a new listing, when i go to the listing table i can see that the user_id and user_email are different and it pulls data from the latest row on the **users** table and not the user that is actually logged in.

Hope i made myself clear.

Here is the code:

this is a file called 'new-listing-functions.php'

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'db.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}



$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$query = "SELECT id, email FROM users";


if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
/* Fetch associative array */ 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $user_id_from_users_table = $row['id'];
    $user_email_from_users_table = $row['email'];
}
$result->free();
}


$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['user_id'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['user_email'];
$_SESSION['listing_title'] = $_POST['listing_title'];
$_SESSION['listing_description'] = $_POST['listing_description'];
$_SESSION['listing_country'] = $_POST['listing_country'];
$_SESSION['listing_city'] = $_POST['listing_city'];
$_SESSION['listing_image'] = $_POST['listing_image'];


$listing_title = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['listing_title']);
$listing_description = $mysqli>escape_string($_POST['listing_description']);
$listing_country = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['listing_country']);
$listing_city = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['listing_city']);
$listing_image = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['listing_image']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO listing (user_id, user_email, listing_title, 
listing_description, listing_country, listing_city, listing_image)".
"VALUES('$user_id_from_users_table','$user_email_from_users_table',
'$listing_title', '$listing_description', '$listing_country', 
'$listing_city', '$listing_image')";




    if($mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Thank you for creating a listing " 
    .$_SESSION['firstname'];
    //header("location: home.php"); 
}



?>
```

And this is the code from the page with the form ('new-listing.php'):

```
<?php 

require 'db.php';
session_start();


if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
header("location: home.php");
}

require 'head.php';


?>

<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUREST_METHOD'] = 'POST') {
if(isset($_POST['post_listing'])) {
    require 'new-listing-functions.php';
}
}


?>



<body id="new-listing">



<div class="new-listing-container">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_email">
        <input type="text" name="listing_title" placeholder="Listing Title">
<br>
        <textarea name="listing_description" id="" cols="30" rows="20" placeholder="Listing Description"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="listing_country" placeholder="Country"><br>
        <input type="text" name="listing_city" placeholder="City"><br>
        <input type="file" name="listing_image""><br>
        <button name="post_listing">Proceed</button>
    </form>
</div><!-- new-listing-container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for every help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should think about using prepared statements (look up `mysqli::prepare` or `pdo`) instead of trying to sanitise and escape input.

That aside, in your `insert` you are using `$user_id_from_users_table` and `$user_email_from_users_table` to populate your listing details.

Based on your code, you should be using `$_SESSION['id']` and `$_SESSION['email']` instead, although these need sanitising or you need to switch to prepared statements before you put raw post data in an `INSERT`

This is because the `$_user_*_from_users_table` values look like they are literally the last obtained value from your users table:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$query = "SELECT id, email FROM users";


if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
/* Fetch associative array */ 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $user_id_from_users_table = $row['id'];
    $user_email_from_users_table = $row['email'];
}
$result->free();
}
```

That being said, I'm a bit confused as to what this is supposed to be achieving, or why you expect this to be any sort of session specific data?

Comment: I used the while loop to get the information from the users table, but i still get the last entry from the users table when i'm logged in with a different user

Comment: You will, because all you're doing is setting each row to 'id' and 'email' until it runs out of loops.  You're not doing anything in that loop except looping through every row in `users`.

Comment: What is the best solution in your opinion?

Comment: Is the id and email in the `$_POST` data the same as the ones you want to insert into the listing

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['user_id']';
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['user_email'];

When i print_r the session, the id and email are blank but everything else is fine

Comment: I'm assuming that if you `print_r($_POST)`, you'll also have nothing for 'user_id' or 'user_email'.   This looks to be because in your form you have `<input type="hidden" name="user_id"><input type="hidden" name="user_email">`, so they don't have any values set at any point?

Comment: On 'new-listing.php' (the page with the form) i set $_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['id']; and $_POST['user_email'] = $_SESSION['email'];
Now it's working! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Right at the start of your code you are selecting all the data from the users table and then looping through it, so your end result is the last entry.

You need to sanitize the user entered email and user id and then use the WHERE parameter in your SELECT query to only fetch the row WHERE id = $id and email = $email

Comment: I did what you suggested, but i still get the last entry from the users table